# Title attribute that with bad English is coming?

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, tooltips

I just noticed that in the [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits) section of the tools, the *'controversial'* tab has the following tooltip text:

> *Edits that with both approve and reject votes*

This is probably supposed to be

> *Edits with both approve and reject votes*

Not a big issue, I know, but I thought it worth a mention.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bug that with fix and next build.